# Automapper -cannot resolve the Generic List

Tags: c#, automapper, codeplex

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<BusinessObject, Proxy.DataContacts.DCObject>()
 .ForMember(x => x.ExtensionData, y => y.Ignore())
 .ForMember(z => z.ValidPlaces, a=> a.ResolveUsing(typeof(ValidPlaces)));
 Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();  

 proxydcObject = Mapper.Map<BusinessObject, Proxy.DataContracts.DCObject>(_instanceOfBusinessObject); //throws an exception saying ValidPlaces could not be resolved

 public class BusinessObject
 {
     public Enum1 Enum1 { get; set; }
     public List<ValidPlaces> ValidPlaces{ get; set; }
 }

 public class ValidPlaces
 {
     public int No { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DCObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public Enum1 Enum1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<ValidPlaces> ValidPlaces{ get; set; }
}
```

Mapper.CreateMap works find when `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` (No exceptions thrown on this line) is called but
when I actually call into the WCF service on the next line which is not shown here the Automapper throws and exception saying ValidPlaces could not be mapped.Works fine if I put Ignore() on the ValidPlaces property but ideally want that passed.

Any AutoMapper experts out there pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to ditch the line for ValidPlaces:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<BusinessObject, Proxy.DataContacts.DCObject>()
 .ForMember(x => x.ExtensionData, y => y.Ignore());
```

Value resolvers are for a custom class to do the value resolution, and must be of type IValueResolver.  That's some defensive coding I should put in place.  But for List of T -> List of U, as long as AutoMapper can map T -> U, it will work.  In your situation, since T == U, then you don't have to do anything extra.  Otherwise, you have to map T to U (but not List of T -> List of U).

Comment: My DCObject has extensiondata but business object doesnt have this property and hence I put that in place else I get an error. Also T==U in my case but I want List<T> translated to List<U>

Comment: That's fine. AutoMapper supports List<T> automatically, without any extra configuration.  I can do this:

    Mapper.Map<int[], List<int>>(new [] {1, 2, 3});

With zero configuration.  You only need to register element types, and since the element types are identical in your case, no extra configuration is needed.  AutoMapper supports assignable types out-of-the-box.